# Sediment in expired Belgian Beer

Tags: belgian-beers

I have 3 bottles of [La Chouffe Blonde Belgian Beer](https://www.saveur-biere.com/fr/biere-bouteille/1481-la-chouffe.html) that is cloudy. It is out of date as of May of last year. Is it ok to drink? Theres a lot of sediment in the bottle. Can I decant or shake and drink?

Thanks.

Comment: Yesterday I drank a Belgian beer with sediment. The day before yesterday I drank a cloudy Belgian beer. Gosh, they were good!

Comment: Don't fear the sediment!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's ok to drink. Belgian beer usually has a lot of sediment to begin with. I've aged Belgian beers for several years. Some taste quite good with that amount of age.  It's up to you if you want the sediment or not. I am a decanting guy but not everyone is. All you can do is pop it in the fridge and try it out!

Answer (score 4):

Sediment and cloudiness are common characteristics of many beers from that area, they aren't a sign of whether it is gone off or not. It may be okay to drink or it may not, it depends how it's been stored. If it's gone bad it's not going to be poison or anything, just unpleasant to taste, so there's no harm in trying it.

Personally I'm in the decant crowd, I usually find the sediment unpleasant, however that's all your personal taste. Treat it as if you'd just bought it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about the sediment, most of it will be yeast and if the beer was preserved properly it will still be alive. It's up to your personal taste to add it or leave it in the bottle. When I sample old bottles I listen to the sound the beer makes when I lift the cap, if it's quiet silent the beer goes down the drain.

I wouldn't age La Chouffe Blonde myself, it's a beer that get's most of it's character from subtle hoppy notes and those are lost once the beer gets older.